# How to insert datetime value in mysql usinf while loop

Tags: mysql, sql

Trying to insert `datetime` value in mysql but not inserting.

```sql
BEGIN
    DECLARE i datetime DEFAULT '2019-01-01 00:00:00';
    WHILE i <= '2019-07-19 13:45:00'; DO
        INSERT INTO support_data.datetime_sequence( date_time ) VALUES(i) 
           SET i = DATE_ADD(select max(date_time) from support_data.datetime_sequence,INTERVAL 1 SECOND);
    END WHILE;
```

Getting this error.

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE i datetime DEFAULT '2019-01-01 00:00:00';
>       WHILE i <= '2019-07-19 13' at line 2

Comment: You can only code like this in a stored program(procedure,function,trigger,event) - are you?

Comment: ok for me. even procedure is not creating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is a stored procedure you have a number of faults 1) superfluous ; before do 2) missing ; after insert 3) no end statement to match begin statement 4) bracketing in set statement is incorrect AND you may not have set delimiters.
Here's a version which works. Note I have removed the db qualifier for the table increased the interval to 60 seconds and added j as a failsafe to exit the loop. All of these you can amend for your purposes.

```
drop table if exists datetime_sequence;
create table datetime_sequence(date_time datetime);

drop procedure if exists p;
delimiter $$
create procedure p()
BEGIN
    DECLARE i datetime DEFAULT '2019-01-01 00:00:00';
    declare j int default 0;
    WHILE i <= '2019-07-19 13:45:00' and j < 10 DO
      INSERT INTO datetime_sequence( date_time ) VALUES(i) ;
        SET i = (select DATE_ADD((select max(date_time) from datetime_sequence),INTERVAL 60 SECOND));
        set j = j + 1;   
    END WHILE;
end $$
delimiter ;

call p();

+---------------------+
| date_time           |
+---------------------+
| 2019-01-01 00:00:00 |
| 2019-01-01 00:01:00 |
| 2019-01-01 00:02:00 |
| 2019-01-01 00:03:00 |
| 2019-01-01 00:04:00 |
| 2019-01-01 00:05:00 |
| 2019-01-01 00:06:00 |
| 2019-01-01 00:07:00 |
| 2019-01-01 00:08:00 |
| 2019-01-01 00:09:00 |
+---------------------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```